# Can I combine several ".CTB" files together into a single file?

Tags: chitu

I've used Chitubox to add supports to a number of models and saved them as .CTB files ready for printing.

If I want to print several of these models at the same time, is it possible to combine them into a single file and to assign each one a different location on the built plate?

Answer (score 1):

The files generated by a resin printer slicer contain exposure reference information as well as an image for each layer to be printed. One could consider to develop a reverse-engineering bit of code to read all of the image layers, overlaying the common z-height with the others to be printed and hope that none of them create overlaps that would destroy the models being printed.

One can, for example, configure PrusaSlicer to create a print file, change the name to *.ZIP and extract the multiple *.PNG files within. Consider how difficult it would be to composite these individual PNG files when combining them with another file or multiple files.

The web site [3dprintknowledge](https://3dprintknowledge.com/how-resin-3d-printers-work-a-guide-for-beginners/) contains a beginner's reference with a useful image:

[image: layer image from resin printer slicer]